# Calculate the relative rotation between two different camera poses, using cv::FindHomography?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

I have two calibrated cameras, with very different lenses and FOVs.
I have a chessboard visible in both.
What i need is to calculate very accurately (within 0.1 of a degree, ideally), the relative rotation between the cameras.

Using the following:

```
bool found_chessboard = cv::findChessboardCorners(imageGray, cv::Size(grid_size_x, grid_size_y), corners1, 0);//    cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
    bool found_chessboard2 = cv::findChessboardCorners(imageGray2, cv::Size(grid_size_x, grid_size_y), corners2, 0);//  cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

    if (found_chessboard && found_chessboard2)
    {
        cv::cornerSubPix(imageGray, corners1, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Size(-1, -1), cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 0.01));
        cv::cornerSubPix(imageGray2, corners2, cv::Size(3, 3), cv::Size(-1, -1), cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 50, 0.01));


        // Calculate the homography
        cv::Mat h = cv::findHomography(corners1, corners2);

        // Warp source image to destination
        warpPerspective(img_src, img_dst, h, cv::Size(img_dst.cols, img_dst.rows));
    }
```

I can calculate the homography matrix, and remap one image to another. This looks good.

Using the decompose with the intrinsic matrix:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> Rs, Ts;
        cv::decomposeHomographyMat(h,
            K2,
            Rs, Ts,
            cv::noArray());
```

Prints 4 possible solutions, but they all look wrong.
As it is being run on raw images, I imagine that lens distortion would effect the results, is this correct?

I have also tried stereo calibration to solve this problem, but the results are variable, and I can only seem to get to within 2 degrees or so of the ground truth.

How can I accurately calculate the rotational difference between two very different cameras?

Comment: afaik: you will first have to transform one of the images to simulate the same camera intrinsic parameters as the other one. And both images probably have to be distortion corrected. But might be wrong.

Comment: You said that you calibrated the camera. Did you correct distortions on both images with? If not, you can do it after chessboard founded with `cv::undistortPoints`